# Localized date format in Java

Tags: java, datetime-format

I have a timestamp in millis and want to format it indicating day, month, year and the hour with minutes precission.

I know I can specify the format like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm");
String formatted = simpleDateFormat.format(900000)
```

But I'd like the format to be localized with the user's locale. I've also tried

```
DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date());
```

But it does not show the hour. How can I do it?

Comment: As a note, it seems that `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(int, int)` calls `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(int, int, Locale)` using `Locale.getDefault()` anyway, at least with the current version of Android.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is using joda time (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) out of the question? If not, then I would wholeheartedly recommend using this wonderful library instead of the cumbersome Java API.

If not, you could use `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(int, int, Locale)`

The first int is the style for hour, the other is the style for time, so try using:

```
DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
String formattedDate = f.format(new Date());
System.out.println("Date: " + formattedDate);
```

See if this suits you.

Output for Locale.GERMANY:
Date: 25.07.13 10:57

Output for Locale.US:
Date: 7/25/13 10:57 AM

Comment: How would u do it in case of Joda-time library?

Answer (score 2):

*`But it does not show the hour. How can I do it?`*

You have to call `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(int, int, Locale)`

`DateFormat.getDateInstance(int, Locale)` => Gets the **date** formatter with the given formatting style for the given locale.

**While**

`DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(int, int, Locale)` => Gets the **date/time** formatter with the given formatting styles for the given locale.

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

You can use [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime-java.time.format.FormatStyle-java.time.format.FormatStyle-) to obtain a locale-specific date format for the ISO chronology.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfLocalized = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT, FormatStyle.SHORT);
        // Test
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();

        System.out.println(dtfLocalized.withLocale(Locale.US).format(date));
        System.out.println(dtfLocalized.withLocale(Locale.UK).format(date));
        System.out.println(dtfLocalized.withLocale(Locale.CHINESE).format(date));
        System.out.println(dtfLocalized.withLocale(Locale.GERMAN).format(date));
        System.out.println(dtfLocalized.withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("tr")).format(date));
        System.out.println(dtfLocalized.withLocale(Locale.getDefault()).format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5/8/21, 10:49 PM
08/05/2021, 22:49
2021/5/8 下午10:49
08.05.21, 22:49
8.05.2021 22:49
08/05/2021, 22:49
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use method `getDateTimeInstance`, of `DateFormat`. Here the `getDateTimeInstance` method takes 3 arguments

1. the style of Date field
2. the style of time field
3. the Locale using which pattern is auto extracted

   ```
   DATE_FORMAT = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.US);
   System.out.println(DATE_FORMAT.format(d));
   DATE_FORMAT = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.FRENCH);
   System.out.println(DATE_FORMAT.format(d));
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this

```
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
    String formatted = simpleDateFormat.format(900000);
    System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.parse(formatted));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) you could detect the system setting and use different time format:

```
String format;

if (DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)) {
  format = "MM/dd/yy, hh:mm";
}
else {
  format = "MM/dd/yy, h:mm aa";
}

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);
formatter.print(new DateTime());
```