# How to get just the localized TIME as string from a "Date" object?

Tags: android, datetime, datetime-format

The title is quite self explanatory.

I realize this might seem trivial and already answered but it is not.

All the answers I found either:

1. Ask for a format to be specified/hardcoded as "yyyyMMdd HH:mm" (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17853274/1514026))
2. Or they return both date and time (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17853313/1514026)).

I need just the time returned from a existing `Date` object as a string in the user's current locale.

Comment: **For future visitors of this page**: The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67449876/10819573) that uses the `java.time` API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be missing something here, but wouldn't the following work?

```
final DateFormat f = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
f.format(new Date()));
```

This outputs e.g.: `10:24:24 AM`

Similarly, if you wish to extract only the date, use `DateFormat.getDateInstance()`.

Comment: True. I don't know how I missed that. Any idea how to use a similar approach to get just the date? I am assuming `getDateInstance()`?